# How to count all row result as 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, count

I have two tables. "tbl_a" which contain fields of patient and hospital, and "tbl_b" which is the consultation.
Now my problem is to only count the patient that has 4 records in "tbl_b" so that if a patient has 4 records in the "tbl_b" then it count as 1.
I want this result only in use of mysql coz and i need this to run in event scheduler.
In short i want to count all patient that has 4 consultation in every hospital. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: What are the fields in tbl_b? How are patients linked up to consultations? Also, do you want to retrieve patients who have ***exactly*** four consultations or just *four or more* consultations?

Answer (score 1):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT patient
FROM tbl_b
GROUP BY patient
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 4
```

Change the `>=` to `=` if you just want patients who have ***exactly*** four consultations instead of four or more.

Perhaps you want the ***count*** of patients who have four or more consultations... in which case you could just wrap the above `SELECT` and count the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(    
    SELECT patient
    FROM tbl_b
    GROUP BY patient
    HAVING COUNT(1) >= 4
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tables patients and consultation Joined by patient_id

```
SELECT * FROM patients
JOIN (SELECT IF(COUNT(patient_id) = 4, patient_id, NULL) AS con 
    FROM consultation 
    GROUP BY patient_id) AS con 
        ON con.patient_id = patients.patient_id
GROUP BY patient_id
```

the joined table would get only numbers fro consultations which are 4 and all others are NULL hence the join clause in the case would result in records of patients having consultations total 4 only

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select *, count(1) 
from table_a a 
inner join table_b b 
inner join on (a.patient_id=b.patient_id) 
group by b.patient_id having count(1) =4
```

Comment: whats the use of the 1 inside the count ?

Comment: @avien, it just counts the existence of a row, even if that row contains `NULL` values. It's the same as `COUNT(*)`... so it's just a matter of style preference.

Comment: and y do you have to make two inner join?

Comment: the consultation table consists of only the patients id, it is  a join to display the data from table a

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
         COUNT(consultation )/4 AS Patient_Number 
 FROM 
         tbl_b

 GROUP BY 
         consultation 
 HAVING
         (COUNT(consultation ) % 4) = 0
```

Comment: I have assumed that you have a column "consultation" else use the column name which count you want to use.